# Verifying exception messages with GoogleTest

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

Is it possible to verify the message thrown by an exception? Currently one can do:

```
ASSERT_THROW(statement, exception_type)
```

which is all fine and good but no where can I find a way to test e.what() is really what I am looking for. Is this not possible via google test?

Comment: Can you not place a `gtest` assertion macro in a `catch` block?

Comment: @A.E.Drew What are you talking about? Where did I mention anything about placing any macro in a catch block? Please don't comment for the sake of commenting

Comment: There is a complete answer there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270078/test-a-specific-exception-type-is-thrown-and-the-exception-has-the-right-propert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506426/get-google-test-exception-throw-message

Answer (score 4):

Something like the following will work.  Just catch the exception somehow and then do `EXPECT_STREQ` on the `what()` call:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include <exception>

class myexception: public std::exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "My exception happened";
  }
} myex;


TEST(except, what)
{
  try {
    throw myex;
    FAIL();  // exception not thrown as expected
  } catch (std::exception& ex) {
      EXPECT_STREQ("My exception happened", ex.what());
  }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate your answer very much, I knew how to do it other ways (and have been doing it for a while now). I just wanted to know if I am missing some kind of extension to the ASSERT_THROW macro that allows me to check e.what() within the macro itself. I didn't want to be writing the try/catch handlers myself.

Comment: This is a bad approach. It does _not_ test the exception gets thrown, it only checks the right message is seen _if_ the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Mr.Boy so what is a good approach? Can you test that it is thrown and also the message is what is expected? Many error paths may throw `runtime_error`, how can I test that a certain runtime error is thrown without changing the code just for the sake of tests?

Comment: You could add a `FAIL()` in the try block after the instruction supposed to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own assertion that allows you to make assertions on the thrown expected exception:

1. In a helper function, catch the exception, make assertions about it, then re-throw it.
2. In an assertion function, call the helper function wrapped in `EXPECT_THROW`.

```
template<typename ExceptionT, typename ActionF, typename ExceptionMatcher>
void ExpectThrowThatHelper(ActionF action, ExceptionMatcher&& exceptionMatcher)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (const ExceptionT& e)
    {
        EXPECT_THAT(e, std::forward<ExceptionMatcher>(exceptionMatcher));
        throw;
    }
}

template<typename ExceptionT, typename ActionF, typename ExceptionMatcher>
void ExpectThrowThat(ActionF action, ExceptionMatcher&& exceptionMatcher)
{
    EXPECT_THROW(ExpectThrowThatHelper<ExceptionT>(std::forward<ActionF>(action), std::forward<ExceptionMatcher>(exceptionMatcher)), ExceptionT);
}
```

This approach applies a matcher to the exception using `EXPECT_THAT`. You could also just pass a function and call it, but since matchers can be built from lambdas, I find it more elegant to support matchers.

You can use this directly as follows:

```
struct GivenException final : std::exception
{
    int Value = 0;

    explicit GivenException(const int value)
        : Value(value)
    {}

    [[nodiscard]] const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return "GivenException";
    }
};

TEST(ExceptionInspectionTest, SomeCode_ThrowsGivenExceptionWithSpecificValue)
{
    using testing::Field;
    using testing::Eq;

    ExpectThrowThat<GivenException>([]
        {
            throw GivenException(123);
        }, Field(&GivenException::Value, Eq(123)));
}
```

If you like preprocessor macros:

```
#define EXPECT_THROW_THAT(ACTION, EXCEPTION, MATCHER) (ExpectThrowThat<EXCEPTION>([]{ACTION;}, (MATCHER)))

TEST(ExceptionInspectionTest, SomeCode_ThrowsGivenExceptionWithSpecificValue)
{
    using testing::Field;
    using testing::Eq;

    EXPECT_THROW_THAT(throw GivenException(123), GivenException, Field(&GivenException::Value, Eq(123)));
}
```

Likewise, you can write `ASSERT_THROW_THAT`, which uses `ASSERT_THROW` and `ASSERT_THAT`.