# Get google test exception throw message

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, googletest

I am using google Test framework for my project. I am throwing exception from the code as:

```
throw DerivedClassException("message");
```

and in the test frame using as:

```
ASSERT_THROW(commond(), DerivedClassException);
```

I want to get message with `what()` API.
Any way to get exact exception message of the exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to check the thrown exception is to catch it in the test :

```
void test_foo( MyTest, TestException )
{
  try
  {
    functionThatThrowsException();
    FAIL();
  }
  catch( const DerivedClassException& err )
  {
    // check exception
    ASSERT_STREQ( "error message", err.what() );
  }
}
```